# CXF call duration logging

Tags: java, logging, cxf

I'm using custom cxf interceptors to log requests/responses for service calls and I would like to log the time it took the call along with the response.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store the start time onto the `Exchange` in your in-interceptor (if you are a server, out-interceptor if you're a client)

```
message.getExchange().put("com.myapp.startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

and retrieve it in the out (respectively in) interceptor

```
long timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - (Long)message.getExchange().get("com.myapp.startTime");
```

Depending exactly where in the chain your existing interceptors sit you may want to do this in a dedicated pair of interceptors, with the in one as early as possible in the chain and the out one as late as possible (for a server, vice-versa if you're a client).

Comment: Is this thread safe? Can I get `com.myapp.startTime` from another request?